# when i am trying to print json on text on widget in flutter i getting this error "Invalid argument(s)"

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[

> this what is display when i Navigator from one screen to other screen

[this is error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC6La.png)

```
 Future palcename() async {
var url='http://milanapp.langdaitechnologies.com/public/index.php/api/getuser/'+widget.value;
var response = await http.get(url);

Map<String,dynamic> user =jsonDecode(response.body);
final welcome = welcomeFromJson(response.body);
var name = welcome.status;
var name1 = "${welcome.data[0].milanName}";

print(name);
//print(datas);

if(response.statusCode==200){
  print("some thing");
  return name1;
}else{
  print("not printed");
}}}
```

i am using name1 variable in appbar
     appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MILAN-"+name1),
        ),

Comment: Please add relevant code that's causing the issue. Seems like you are setting null to a Text widget

Comment: From where you are calling `palcename` and how you are showing the result in the ui ?

Comment: add code where you are using name and name1 variable also add where you are calling this method.